# ImportError: No module named selenium

Tags: python, selenium

On a Mac running Yosemite and Python 3 scripts...

I have a Python script running under my main user account perfectly.  I set up a second user account on the same computer to run the same script but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dan2/Documents/Scripts/my_script.py", line 15, in <module> from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

I ran python3, help(), modules, and selenium is listed as a module, just like it is in my main user account. Any ideas?

Comment: what does `which -a python3` output?

Comment: and in your second user account try: `python3 -c "import selenium"` and see if it returns an error.

Comment: also, in your second account `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)` and in your first account `python3 -c 'import selenium; print(selenium.__file__)'` to see where it's installed and why its not in the pythonpath of your second account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check your paths for each user as there may be one for your main user not included in the second user.

Try running the following commands on each user and comparing the output:

- Find out what Python interpreter is being used by each account

  `$ which python3`
- Find out the directories in your Python path for each account and compare the number present:

  `$ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path); print(len(sys.path))"`
- Finally find out where selenium is being imported from by the main user:

  `$ python3 -c "import selenium; import os; print(selenium.__file__); print(os.path.dirname(selenium.__file__))"`

  Check this path is in the `sys.path` for your second user above.